# Spark missing 99.9% messages while reading from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, bigdata

TL;DR : My spark app is ingesting 0.1% of the total msgs sent from Kafka.
my prime suspect : For each batch interval (1sec in this eg) new JVM is instantiated. I am trying to ingest data using .map() transformation which is lazy loaded. Is it possible that driver & executor code being mutually exhaustive might have something to do here ?

Long version with details :

My event flow is as follows : a java class to produce sample (.json as strings) data & run using Kafka's kafka-run-class.sh script. The messages are collected in kafka from where spark reads them using java directstream. For the sake of brevity lets assume my data producer sends json msg with a value which can either be 1 or 0 & Spark app's purpose is to distinguish 1's & 0's. The data generator is also appending a count value to the sent msg.

Problem : On experimenting, I am sending 10000 msgs from data generator. I'v a kibana dashboard for this incoming data & it shows 9600 msgs (+-0.1% but consistently seen)

Q1. Where are the rest of 400 msgs lost ?

Now spark (with a batch interval of 1sec & running on 1 thread) reads these msgs & its output I'v fed into same kibana under another visualization.

it reads 10 (or sometimes 20) msgs consistently.

if it reads 10 msgs, those have count value 1-10 & if it reads 20 msgs, the count values are 1-10 & ~3000-3010

Q2. Why is Spark only getting 10 (or at max 20) msgs ?

I changed the setting "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" in Spark app but that hasn't really helped. it just reads 10 msgs from count 1-10.

Q3. What needs to be done to make it read from the start of kafka topic ?

1 thing I can think of being the spoil sport here is that I am ingesting msgs in .map function :

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = stream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
  public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
  my_fn(tuple2._2().toString());
  return tuple2._2();
}
```

Can someone shed some light on window and reduce functions & how it may be related to spark seeing 0.1% of the total msgs ?

Note : I am using logstash instances to migrate data from spark->kafka, kafka->elastic

I needed to manipulate json obj in data generator script. I am using maven & used json dependency & it built fine. but on trying to run the class using kafka-run-class.sh it threw classNotFoundException for json objects.

Q4. How can I run a shaded jar using kafka-run-class method OR would it need to be run as independent java program, in that case would it emit out msgs at the same rate as it does when run using kafka's out of the box script as I think it does take care of parallelizing & queuing to maintain back pressure.

using this kafka script I was able to ooze out 1.4Mpps on my machine.

Edit : More info regarding kafka-spark partition  & code logic

Legend: 
topic_1 is the data from producer (script) -> kafka
topic_2 is the data emitted from Spark->kafka

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic topic_1 
          Topic:topic_1 PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs: 
          Topic: topic_1 Partition: 0   Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0 

curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index          pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   topic_1     5   1   11002386            0    702.1mb        702.1mb 
yellow open   topic_2     5   1       6307            0    786.4kb        786.4kb 
yellow open   .kibana         1   1          9            0       47kb        47kb
```

Spark, I am running with 1 executor & 1 driver with 4GB driver & executor memory on 1 thread on 4 cores with 1 sec batch interval
On experimenting with 10M+msgs, topic_1 received almost correct number (9600/10000 Q1 above) meanwhile topic_2 could get mere ~6k messages 
Regarding partitions, everything is on a standalone mode on same machine with 32GB ram & 4 cores. By everything I mean, data producer, Kafka, ELK, spark.

Data_gen : Simple java kafka producer code to send json strings with value 0 or 1 at 1:1 ratio. 
Spark_app : code in main qn. my_fn() gets the string msg, converts it into json & sees if the value is 0 or 1

Comment: This question has too much detail about stuff we don't need, and is missing a concise, reproduceable test case that illustrates your problem. The one answer I can give you is for Q3 -- to read from the beginning of a Topic you have to use one of the versions of `createDirectStream` that has a `fromOffsets` parameter, and then you have to set the offsets using that parameter. You will need to know exactly what your partitions look like to use that parameter -- or you better be prepared to go fetch partition / offset info out of Kafka. For testing, you can just hardcode in partitions & offsets.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGriffin. I'l try out your suggestion for Q3. but Q2 is more of a blocker to me. Can u pls tell what all info were u looking for ? too much detail has never been a problem ;)

Comment: Do you know your broker layouts? What partitions are sitting where? How many executors are you running? What's the actual code look like? Ideally a start to finish use case: A recipe we can follow to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Edit your answer please, not in the comments!

Comment: @DavidGriffin Pls let me know what further info is reqd. Kafka is running with bare min changes in kafka server.properties & same is the case with zookeeper. 
Pls give clis to extract out broker layouts &/or kafka's internal partioning logic.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Hey David, I was hoping if I can benefit from your experience. Pls have a look. this is a major roadblock for me.

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious, sorry. Wish I had more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map() transformations are lazy so they don’t like to work until asked for.
I was expecting messages in a map() transformation.
put this expectation in rdd.take() which in non-lazy inside foreachRDD()
It worked.
```